# Access denied during production

Tags: vb.net

The code below works as intended in DEBUG with no errors. I input my search parameters, the record returns and populates all textboxes and loads the PDF file into the AxAcroPDF1 viewer.

However, after I compile and install the program I am receiving the error "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NAME OF PROGRAM\temp.file' is denied'

This only occurs when I search for a record and the PDF (in Binary format in the DB) to that record is supposed to load fails with the error message listed above. How can I resolve the permissions level (assuming this is the issue) to allow for the PDF to load? The area of concern presumably and more specifically is the LoadPDF() sub.

My code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class LoadDocs
Private DV As DataView
Private currentRow As String

```
Private Sub LoadDocs_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DocDataset.Documents_Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Documents_TableTableAdapter.Fill(DocDataset.Documents_Table)
    'Loads last record on to form
    DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position = DocDataset.Documents_Table.Rows.Count - 1

    DV = New DataView(DocDataset.Documents_Table)
    'LoadPDF()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnOpenPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenPDF.Click
    tbRecNumb.Clear()
    tbFileName.Clear()
    tbPetsLoadNumber.Clear()
    tbBrokerLoadNumber.Clear()
    tbFilePath.Clear()

    Dim CurYear As String = CType(Now.Year(), String)

    On Error Resume Next
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    AxAcroPDF1.src = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    tbFilePath.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    Dim filename As String = tbFilePath.Text.ToString
    tbFileName.Text = filename.Substring(Math.Max(0, filename.Length - 18))

    Dim loadnumber As String = tbFileName.Text
    tbPetsLoadNumber.Text = loadnumber.Substring(7, 7)
End Sub

' Search for PETS Load Number, Broker Load Numberthen load record if found
Private Sub BtnSearchBtn_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.MouseEnter
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    btnSearch.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ButtonDwn_Teal_Trans
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSearchBtn_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.MouseLeave
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
    btnSearch.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Button_Teal_Trans
End Sub

Private Sub TbSearchInput_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbSearchInput.KeyDown
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Search()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    btnSearch.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ButtonClk_Teal_Trans
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    Search()
End Sub

Private Sub Search()
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    If cbColName.Text = "SEARCH BY:" Then
        MeMsgBoxSearchCriteria.ShowDialog()
    Else : lblSearchResults.Items.Clear()
        Select Case DocDataset.Documents_Table.Columns(cbColName.Text).DataType
            Case GetType(Integer)
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = " & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim
            Case GetType(Date)
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = #" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "#"
            Case Else
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " LIKE '*" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "*'"
        End Select

        If DV.Count > 0 Then
            For IX As Integer = 0 To DV.Count - 1
                lblSearchResults.Items.Add(DV.Item(IX)("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER"))
            Next
            If DV.Count = 1 Then
                lblSearchResults.SelectedIndex = 0
                Dim ix As Integer = DocumentsTableBindingSource.Find("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER", CInt(lblSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString))
                DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position = ix
                LoadPDF()
            Else
                lblSearchResults.Visible = True
                lblSearchResults.BringToFront()
            End If
        Else
            ' Display a message box notifying users the record cannot be found.   
            MeMsgBoxNoSearch.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End If
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Private Sub LblSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSearchResults.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ix As Integer = DocumentsTableBindingSource.Find("PETS_LOAD_NUMBER", CInt(lblSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString))
    DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position = ix
    lblSearchResults.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub LoadPDF()
    Dim temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)

    If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file") = True Then
        AxAcroPDF1.src = "blank.pdf"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file")
    End If

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DOCUMENTS FROM Documents_Table WHERE PETS_LOAD_NUMBER = @pl"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pl", tbPetsLoadNumber.Text)

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection With {
            .ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.PETS_DatabaseConnectionString
        }

    Dim Buffer As Byte()

    cmd.Connection.Open()
    Buffer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    cmd.Connection.Close()

    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file", Buffer)
    'DATA READER
    AxAcroPDF1.src = Application.StartupPath() & "\temp.file"
End Sub

Private Sub DocumentsTableBindingSource_PositionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DocumentsTableBindingSource.PositionChanged
    Try
        currentRow = DocDataset.Documents_Table.Item(DocumentsTableBindingSource.Position).ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSavePDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSavePDF.Click
    If tbPetsLoadNumber.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a PETS Load Number", "Missing Load Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf tbBrokerLoadNumber.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Broker Load Number", "Missing Load Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf tbFileName.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Filename", "Missing Filename", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        Using OpenFileDialog As OpenFileDialog = OpenFileDialog1()
            If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK) Then
                tbFilePath.Text = OpenFileDialog.FileName

            Else 'Cancel
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End Using

        'Call Upload Images Or File
        Dim sFileToUpload As String = ""

        sFileToUpload = LTrim(RTrim(tbFilePath.Text))

        'Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
        Dim data As Byte() = Nothing

        'Use FileInfo object to get file size.
        Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(tbFilePath.Text)
        Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length

        'Open FileStream to read file
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(tbFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        'Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)

        'Supply number of bytes to read from file.
        'In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
        data = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))

        'Insert the details into the database
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Documents_Table (BROKER_LOAD_NUMBER, PDF_FILENAME, PETS_LOAD_NUMBER, DOCUMENTS) 
                           VALUES (@bl, @fn, @pl, @pdf)"

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = tbFileName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pl", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tbPetsLoadNumber.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bl", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = tbBrokerLoadNumber.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdf", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = data

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection With {
            .ConnectionString = My.MySettings.Default.PETS_DatabaseConnectionString
        }
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()

        MsgBox("File Successfully Imported to Database")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\" is a special directory that you do not have all privileges by code. To store temp files, you must use dedicated directories for temp files like "AppData\Local\Temp" or somewhere else.

Comment: Note that the right way to get the temp directory is to use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath`.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj - Your solution is correct and changing the temp directory as both you and Craig noted, resolved my issue. Thanks much!

Comment: @K3JAE To get the correct path you can use the  shared readOnly property  `Temp`  by `SpecialDirectories.Temp` importing  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace

Answer (score 0):

In your function `LoadPDF` you create a reference to tempdir and then don't use it. Instead, you use `Application.StartupPath()` which will point to C:\Programs(x86) and is usually not writeable without admin rights.

But why don't you use your temp dir:

```
    Dim temp = SpecialDirectories.Temp 'more robust approach to get tempdir

    If File.Exists(temp & "\temp.file") = True Then
        AxAcroPDF1.src = "blank.pdf"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(temp & "\temp.file")
    End If
...

    File.WriteAllBytes(temp & "\temp.file", Buffer)
    'DATA READER
    AxAcroPDF1.src = temp & "\temp.file"
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a more robust alternative for getting the temp path (there are already a couple in the question comments) over reading the TEMP environment variable.

Comment: Agreed, I just wanted to point out that they probably planned to use the TEMPDIR but simply forgot.

Comment: @Craig - Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @K3JAE I was referring to my comment and G3nt_M3caj's comment on the question, both of which provide ways of getting an appropriate temp path.  That is, `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Temp`.